# "Source" VsDevCmd.bat from Cygwin

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2015, cygwin

So `VsDevCmd.bat` is a nifty script that sets environment variables for Visual Studio tools:

'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat'

I am using Visual Studio tools `cl`, `link`, etc. from Cygwin. How can I use that script to set all the same environment variable without reinventing the script in bash?

I can run the batch script from cmd shell then launch bash, but this is unsatisfactory—I need to initiate the process of "sourcing" the batch file from within Cygwin.

Comment: By chance, would you have the command to "run the batch script from cmd shell then launch bash" ? I cannot manage to find the command that start a command inside the developer shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with. This bash function will ran `cmd` with `VcVarsAll.bat` file, then will a nested `bash` in order to print an environment variable, which could be extracted:

```
# Given envar names return their newline-separated values setup for VS2015
#
# VcVarsAll.bat is a script that sets up environment variables for Visual
# Studio command-line builds:
#
#   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx
#
query_vcvarsall() {
  local envars=$*

  (cd '/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC' &&
   cmd /c "VcVarsAll.bat amd64 && c:/cygwin/bin/bash -c 'printenv $envars'")
}
```

Then set, for example, `PATH`:

```
export PATH="$(query_vcvarsall PATH)"
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this! Works like a charm for VS 2019 with minor editions - here's the snippet from MSYS2 .bashrc:

`query_vsdevcmd() {
  local envars=$*

  (cd '/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/Tools' &&
   cmd /c "VsDevCmd.bat && c:/msys64/usr/bin/bash -c 'printenv $envars'")
}

export PATH="$(query_vsdevcmd PATH):$PATH"`

Comment: It turned out that VsDevCmd.bat produces copyright header in output, thus it must be invoked with output redurection to nul, e.g. `cmd /c "VsDevCmd.bat >nul && ...`. Also, it's worth to add at least INCLUDE and LIB env vars as well so default headers from installed SDKs will be available.

Comment: @AndreiBelov, `vsdevcmd -no_logo` supresses the Copyright notification.

Answer (score 2):

I found that all you need is the path.

Run VsDevCmd.bat from DOS, then pipe out SET to a file (`SET > c:\temp\set.txt`)

From that file extract the PATH and convert it to Linux format - `C:\Program Files` becomes `/cygdrive/c/Program Files` and the `\` all become `/`. The replace the `;` with `:`.

Then edit your "${HOME}/.bashrc" file - append the above to the PATH - don't forget to add a `:` to the end of the original path.

My "${HOME}/.bashrc" now says the following - but copy it at your own risk.

> export PATH="/c/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/HostX86/x86:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/VC/VCPackages:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/TypeScript/2.3:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/bin/Roslyn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Team Tools/Performance Tools:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/HTML Help Workshop:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional//MSBuild/15.0/bin:C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/Tools/:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/HostX86/x86:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/VC/VCPackages:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/TypeScript/2.3:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/bin/Roslyn:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Team Tools/Performance Tools:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/HTML Help Workshop:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional//MSBuild/15.0/bin:C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/Tools/:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Windows Kits/8.0/bin/x86:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/F#/3.0/Framework/v4.0/:C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/CMake/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin"

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to set the environment variables locally, so I used export instead of printenv.  This makes it easy to source the output, as it's already in a format designed to export environment variables.

```
cmd /c "VsDevCmd.bat -no_logo && bash -c 'export' > vcvars.tmp"
source vcvars.tmp
rm vcvars.tmp
```

Comment: It looks like `vcvarsall.bat` does not support the `-no_logo` flag. However, I believe it can be left out since `export` is being used.